# How to run my Pine Script code where has options so that I can get my list?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The code is error free, it does get saved.

How can I get my filtered stocks list?

I am not able to run it to obtain the results.

```
//@version=5
//@author=YourName

// This script scans for stocks whose 44MA and 200MA are both strictly increasing.

indicator("MA Cross", overlay=true)

// Calculate the moving averages
ma44 = ta.sma(close, 44)
ma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)

// Check if both moving averages are strictly increasing
ma44_increasing = ta.change(ma44) > 0
ma200_increasing = ta.change(ma200) > 0

// Condition to find stocks with strictly increasing moving averages
condition = ma44_increasing and ma200_increasing

// Plotting the condition on the chart
plotshape(condition, title="Condition Met", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, text="MA Increasing")

// Printing the list of stocks that meet the condition
var stocks = ""
if condition
    stocks := syminfo.ticker + ", " + stocks

// Displaying the list of stocks
label.new(bar_index, high, text="Stocks: " + stocks, color=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)
```

[IMAGE OF MY LAPTOP SCREEN SHOWING MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpb0S.png)

Comment: Please write a more meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run your script in a screener. You need to code that part too using [request.security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) and getting values from different tickers.

You cannot scan the whole market. There is a limit for the number of `security()` calls you can have in your script and that is 40. So, you can only scan 40 tickers if you are looking at one timeframe only.